# How to push a table view AND be able to put data in the cells from a segue?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, segue

I have a first table view and a segue that pushes to another table view. I'm already able to push the second table view when the user touches a cell from the first table view, but I can't but data in the second table view. My second table view is using my custom controller which inherits from UITableViewController. I use the method "cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath" to put text in my cells, but the code never gets to that method. I don't understand what the problem is.

Here is my custom class:

```
    #import "TableViewControllerTop.h"

    @interface TableViewControllerTop ()

    @end

    @implementation TableViewControllerTop
    @synthesize tableView;
    @synthesize cells;

    - (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
    {
        self = [super initWithStyle:style];
        if (self) {
            // Custom initialization
        }
        return self;
    }

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
        // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

        // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
    }

    - (void)viewDidUnload
    {
        [self setTableView:nil];
        [self setCells:nil];
        [super viewDidUnload];
        // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
        // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
    }

    - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
    {
        return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
    }

    #pragma mark - Table view data source

    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    {
    #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
        // Return the number of sections.
        return 0;
    }

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
#warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 6;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Top 50 list";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell...

    cell.textLabel.text = @"Test";

    return cell;
}


#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"selected");
}

@end
```

Thanks for your help. I can post more code if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your code is returning 0 for number of sections. So therefore it thinks there is nothing to show.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
#warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: OMG, it works! I though that by default it would make one big section! In fact, I just remove the method so Xcode, by defaut, makes one big! I misunderstood something there. Thank you!